# Image is partly clipped

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have received a table-html designed site to complete it. Now I have encountered a problem and need your help. Would it be possible for you to see why the top right image is not displayed completely? I have tried a a lot and found nothing.

Here is the link to homepage:

http://myperfume.ir/

Here is the link to full image so that you can see how much it is clipped:

http://8pic.ir/images/03017006756162873819.jpg

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the language there but image seems fine to me

Comment: [Don't use tables for styling](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm)

Comment: fine for me too, which browser you are using?

Comment: It's not fine. Look at the two top left characters. They're cut.

Comment: yes. don't care about the language. because if you look at the picture you can understand a little part of it at the top is clipped off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image that is being used as the row's background is this:

http://myperfume.ir/images/2_02.png

Which is already clipped, so you'll need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to recode the entire website without using tables. You are going to have all kinds of headaches with this structure.

Comment: yes I know that. I never use tables. This is just a delegation to me